# Pandas rolling regression by group

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the coefficient from the regression for each cusip at each point in time. The result of my rolling window regression is a dataframe with one column for a cusip and one column being a list of tuples containing (date, coefficient).

Here's my code so far:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['exretn'])


def rolling_window_regression(data, window_size, min_obs=24, n_jobs=-1):
    results = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs)(
        delayed(regress)(data[i:i+window_size], min_obs=min_obs)
        for i in range(len(data)-window_size+1)
        if len(data[i:i+window_size]) >= min_obs
    )
    if not results:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return results

def regress(data, min_obs):
    if len(data) < min_obs:
        return np.nan
    X = data[['mkt_rf']]
    y = data['exretn']
    model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(X, y)
    coefficients = model.coef_[0]
    date = data['date'].iloc[-1]
    return (date, coefficients)


results = df.groupby('cusip')\
    .apply(lambda x: rolling_window_regression(x, 36, 24))\
    .reset_index()
```

Instead of a column containing a list of tuples, I would like to get two columns, one for date and one for the coefficient. So my results dataframe would have one line for each cusip-date-coefficient. The regressions must be parallelized due to the size of the dataset.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of your data.